# ¿Cual es la mejor manera de utilizar metodos setters con objectos?

Tags: java

tengo una duda, cual es la manera mas eficiente o que siga algun estandar de inicializar objectos para metodos setters, en mi trabajo ha posiciones divididas entre uso de memoria y tiempo de ejecución ¿que opinan ustedes?

**1ra forma:**

```
ObjectA objA = new ObjectA(data);
objA.setother(other);

ObjectB objB = new ObjectB();
objB.setObjectA(objA):
```

**2da forma**

```
ObjectB objB = new ObjectB();
objB.setObjectA(new ObjectA(data)):
objB.getObjectA().setother(other);
```

Comment: Las dos formas hacen lo mismo. No es que una sea mejor que la otra. Sino que se adaptan dependiendo de lo que necesites.

Comment: Dado que tu pregunta invita a los usuarios a expresar su opinión, debe ser cerrada. Por favor, revisa las directrices de calidad en esta guía: _[ask]_.

Comment: Esta pregunta es bastante amplia, ya que para elegir una forma se debe justificar el por que. Te recomiendo que leas sobre patrones de creación. Quizá esto te de una idea de lo que debes seguir leyendo https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o  y https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_de_dependencias

Comment: Gracias por responder, revisare esos links, siempre esta en mi mente cual es la manera correcta y no encontraba como buscar este tema puntual en internet

Comment: Si lees los [pasos que ejecuta la JVM cuando se  crea una nueva instancia de clase](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.5) podrás sacar algunas conclusiones interesantes. La que yo he sacado es que, si la creación de la nueva instancia es lo más sencilla posible: `ObjectA objA = new ObjectA();`, mejor. Aunque no creo que haya demasiado diferencia... la JVM opera de forma muy rápida, la mayoría de cosas que hace, ni nos enteramos. [Esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19359582/5587982) da otro aspecto: ¿objetos mutables o inmutables?